# Dynamically generating css locally

Tags: css

Is there any way to take css file as input and modify its property and values? Or any application which helps us to dynamically generate css?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to change? Can you give an example of a slice of code you want to change, and what code you'd want it to be changed to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are frameworks to dynamically generate CSS. For .NET you can look at [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/), or for Java there is the [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) framework on which it is based. There will doubtless be others if you're not working with either of these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery functions. It can perfectly change CSS styles on the fly by using JavaScript